# re rank column values based on condition value to be like Number line (-2,-1,0,1,2,3)

Tags: python

I have data for car renting with the following columns: (Person_ID, rent_ID, date_of_renting,accident_Flag, rank_per_accident_1, rank_per_accident_2, rank_per_accident_3, rank_per_accident_4 )
noting that:

- accident_Flag will be "Yes" to indicate the people who rented a car and had an accident.
- Each person could have more than one accident and others could not have any accident
- I need to reindex the rows or re-rank the rows per person ID so if the person has one accident then the column value of "rank_per_accident_1" with with first accident_Flag ='Yes'  will be 0 and all rows above it will be -1, -2, -3, and so on, and all car rent rows after it will be 1, 2, 3
- for the second accident "the second yes" per person , the value of "rank_per_accident_2" column will be  0 (FOR THE second ACCIDENT "second Yes") and all rows above it will be -1, -2, -3, and so on, and all car rent rows after it will be 1, 2, 3

and so on for rank_per_accident_3 for the third yes and rank_per_accident_4 for the fourth yes.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['x','iii-2019-10-16A','18/04/2020','No'],
                   ['x','iii-2019-10-16B','18/04/2021','No'],
                   ['x','iii-2019-10-16C','12/09/2022','Yes'],
                   ['x','zzz-2020-10-25','12/04/2023','No'],
                   ['y','zzz-2021-10-25','10/12/2017','No'], 
                   ['r','qqq-2018-05-28','15/02/2018','Yes'],
                   ['y','ooo-2019-11-22','30/05/2019','Yes'],
                   ['y','rrr-16-12-2020','16/12/2020','No'],
                   ['z','ppt3-2019-12-03','16/12/2020','No'],
                   ['y','ppt2-2019-12-04','16/12/2021','Yes'],
                   ['y','ppt1-2019-12-04','16/12/2022','No'],
                   ['z','ttt-2019-12-03','18/04/2019','No'],
                   ['z','ttt-2019-12-03','15/02/2018','No']
                  
                  ],
                  columns=['Person_ID','rent_ID','date_of_renting','accident_Flag '])
df['date_of_renting'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_renting'])
df = df.sort_values(['Person_ID','date_of_renting'], ascending = [True, True])
df
#,'rank_per_accident_1','rank_per_accident_2', 'rank_per_accident_3'
```

the expected result :
[image]